# Tracking download progress with UIProgressView and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using ASINetworkQueue to download a series of images to be displayed in a particular view.

Mi problem is when I open the view and then close it right away, before the request finishes, it takes a while when the UIProgressView is attempted to updated, and then it crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) as it doesn't exist anymore (the view was dismissed). I tried setting the delegate to nil before unloading the view but it doesn't help.

This is the part of the code in charge of creating the queue and adding the requests

```
- (void)doNetworkOperations
{
    // Stop anything already in the queue before removing it
    [[self networkQueue] cancelAllOperations];

    // Creating a new queue each time we use it means we don't have to worry about clearing delegates or resetting progress tracking
    [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];

    // if I have little files to download, use accurate progress
    // if I have lots, it's not worth it.
    if ([promosInfo count]<=4) {
        [[self networkQueue] setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    }
    [[self networkQueue] setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressControl];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];

    NSInteger i=0;
    for (id row in promosInfo){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [row objectForKey:@"imgSource"]];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL: url];
        [request setTag:i];
        [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
        i++;
        url = nil;
        request = nil;
    }

    [[self networkQueue] go];
}
```

And I have the following viewDidUnload

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[self networkQueue] setDownloadProgressDelegate:nil];
    [[self networkQueue] cancelAllOperations];
    [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    [self setCargando:nil];
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    [self setPageControl:nil];
    [self setStatusLabel:nil];
    [self setProgressControl:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

How do I tell the ASINetworkQueue to stop tracking progress? As I mentioned, I tried setting the delegate to nil but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following code and achieve the functionality of progress Bar.....

1. In class where I am going to download and saving progressBar as a value of Key having url different for each request in a dictionary and then saving that dictionary into class name Singleton.

   ```
       UIProgressView *_progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
       ASIHTTPRequest *request;
       request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trimmedString]];
       [request setDelegate:self];
       [request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
       [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:_progressBar];
       [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
       [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
       [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadedSuccessfully:)];
       [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadedFailure:)];
       [[[MySingleton sharedSingleton ]getProgressValue] setValue:_progressBar forKey:trimmedString];
   ```

And then in the view controller where i am going to show progress bar, I wrote the following code:It reads the value for each cell's progress bar from dictionary from Singleton class and show in table. If completed it dont show because in dic the value will be nil, but you have to reload table for this.

```
UIProgressView *progressBar = (UIProgressView *)[[[MySingleton sharedSingleton] getProgressValue] valueForKey:[dictionary valueForKey:@"SongUrl"]];
    [progressBar setFrame:CGRectMake(215, 27, 40, 10)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:progressBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this code in viewDidUnload to see if its works.

```
for (ASIFormDataRequest *req in [networkQueue operations]) {
    [req cancel];
    [req setDelegate:nil];
}

[networkQueue reset];
[networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
[networkQueue setDelegate:nil];
```

Comment: I really tought your solution will do it but it still tries to access the UIProgressView and gets a bad access.

Answer (score -2):

I finally made it work by changing the cancel requests, set delegate to nil and similar from ViewDidLoad to ViewWillDissapear:(BOOL)Animated.